# fppf-extension of algebraic groups is an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes, grothendieck-topology

The problem is the following:

> Let $k$ be a field and let $N,G,Q: (\operatorname{Sch}/k)_{\operatorname{fppf}} \longrightarrow \operatorname{Grps}$
>   be fppf-sheaves from the big fppf-site of $\operatorname{Sch}/k$ to the
>   category of groups. Assume that we have an exact sequence of
>   fppf-sheaves $$ e\longrightarrow N \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow
> Q \longrightarrow e $$ and that $N$ and $Q$ are both algebraic group
>   schemes. Then $G$ is representable by an algebraic group scheme.

I know that after some fppf base change  $Q'\longrightarrow Q$ we have an equality 
$$
G\times_Q Q' \cong N\times_k Q'
$$
and so it becomes representable. Moreover, if $N$ is affine I can use fppf-descent obtaining the desired scheme. Nevertheless I am not sure how to deal with the general case.

This is an exercise of  Milne's book on Algebraic Groups (Ex 5-10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible road to a solution (I am fairly sure that Milne had something more elementary in mind). Algebraic spaces satisfy fppf descent; hence $G$ is a group object is in the category of algebraic spaces of finite type over $k$. But it is well known that a group object is in the category of finitely generated algebraic spaces over a field is in fact a group scheme. This seems to be "well known", although I have never seen a complete proof. Over an algebraically closed field this follows immediately from the result of Grothendieck that every algebraic space contains a dense open subscheme. In the general case this requires a little more care.

Comment: You can complete the argument using my answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/194326 plus the fact that algebraic group schemes over a field are quasiprojective.